# Why Rails not found my AJAX partial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on AJAX + Bootstrap Modal in Rails. I got problem with the modal where it's not showing when I click the `.btn_new` button.

It says that it couldn't found that `popup`.

[image]

I found that this problem is only exist on my local machine. When I try to clone the project on my friends machines, the modal box is showing properly.

I've no idea what's missing here.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :customers do
    resources :users, only: [:index]

    resources :calendars, only: [:index] do
      post 'popup', on: :collection
    end
  end
```

**calendars_controller.rb**

```
def popup
    if params[:daily_order_id].blank?
      @exclude_kitchens = @customer.ordered_kitchens(params[:date])
      @daily_order = @customer.new_default_or_blank_order(params[:date])
    else
      @daily_order = DailyOrder.find(params[:daily_order_id].to_i)
    end
    @max_pax = DailyOrder.allowable_pax(@daily_order.id, @daily_order.date,
                                        @daily_order.kitchen_id)
    respond_to :js
  end
```

**views/calendars/index.html.erb**

```
    <%= button_tag type: 'button', 'data-date': date.strftime('%F'),
           class: 'btn btn-xs btn-default btn_new' do-%>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-primary"></i>
           <%-end if date >= earliest_editable_day &&
             !date.saturday? && !date.sunday? %>
        <% end %>
...

<div class="modal fade" id="orderModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
 aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/calendars/popup.js.erb**

```
var order_modal = $('#orderModal')

<% if @daily_order.editable? %>
  order_modal.find('.modal-content').html("<%= j render('calendars/form') %>")
<% else %>
  order_modal.find('.modal-content').html(
  "<%= j render partial:'order_info', locals:{ daily_order: @daily_order } %>")
<% end %>

order_modal.modal('show')
```

**assets/javascripts/calendars.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_new', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: location.pathname + '/popup',
    type: "POST",
    data: { "daily_order_id": '',
            "date": new Date( $(this).attr('data-date') ) }
  });
});
```

My development environment:

- Ruby: 2.2.0
- Rails: 4.2.0
- PostgreSQL: 9.4.4
- I'm using Mac OSX 10.11 with `brew` installed.

What should I do now?

Comment: Try to add `dataType: 'script',` to the `$.ajax({})` call.

Comment: @Зелёный still not working.

Comment: Please show a piece of log Rails file, with related request.

Comment: @Зелёный here you go - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7494723ff9a2ab0b2bdf

Comment: Your error internal in Rails action `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Kitchen with 'id'=1):`, happens in `allowable_pax` method.

Comment: @Зелёный thanks for pointing out. I'll try to figure it out!